# How to change or manage the "Carbon" timezone so it doesn't move the clock back and forth

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, php-carbon

I use Laravel and I deployed my application on Docker 
I use carbon package for time management and I set the timezone to Asia/Tehran But now I found a problem and the time are moved forward one hour and I don't want this one hour to move forward.
Is there a solution for me to move back one hour?

```
Carbon::now("Asia/Tehran"); //  Asia/Tehran (+04:30)
```

But i need this

```
Carbon::now("Asia/Tehran"); //  Asia/Tehran (+03:30)
```

Comment: Is it related daylight savings time?

Comment: Yes,it is......

Comment: What timezone is your (docker) web server running in? FWIW I would generally suggest running both server in UTC and Laravel in UTC otherwise it can get real messy. You can then convert to local timezones as necessary when accessing or displaying dates...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `timezonedb` package solve your issue

```
pecl install timezonedb
```

or simply download and install it
https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb/

after install add this line to `php.ini`

```
extension=timezonedb.so
```

Answer (score 2):

DateTime (and so Carbon) relies on https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb to know which city has which offsets. You need to update it to get the latest info. If it's not yet available you'll need to ask the offset explitcly:

```
Carbon::now('+03:30')
```